# Populate Textarea with Html/Javascript while keeping it decoupled with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to populate a textarea with dynamic code that changes with an event id change on the client.  My below implementation is below and Im not sure if there's a better way.  I ran into two problems with it.  The first is I want to remove the data-bind elements after binding the html, and showing it in the textarea, and second the javascript is disappearing.  Thoughts?  I am trying to do what Google Analytics does when you copy and paste their code, but mine is dynamic on the page.

**View Model**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    app.viewModel.members.widgets = {
        type: ko.observable(),
        code: ko.observable(),
        list: [
            { id: 'registration', type: '@((int)WidgetType.Registration)' },
            { id: 'payments', type: '@((int)WidgetType.Payments)' }
        ]
    };


    app.viewModel.members.widgets.selectedWidget = ko.computed(function() {

        if (!app.viewModel.members.widgets.type())
            return null;

        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(app.viewModel.members.widgets.list, function(widget) {
            return widget.type == app.viewModel.members.widgets.type();
        });
    });


    ko.bindingHandlers.initializeValueWithHtml = {
        update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                value($(element).html());
            }
        }
    };

</script>
```

**Input**

```
<textarea data-bind="value: code, click: function(vm, e)  { $(e.currentTarget).select(); } ">
            </textarea>
```

**Template**

```
   <pre class="hidden" data-bind="if: $root.members.widgets.selectedWidget(), initializeValueWithHtml: code">
            <div data-bind="attr: { id: 'ebt-' + $root.members.widgets.selectedWidget().id,  'data-href': 'https://test.com/widgets/v1/' +  $root.members.widgets.selectedWidget().id + '?eventid=@Model.EventId    ' }" data-width="100%" data-height="500px"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                (function (d, s, id) {
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                    if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                        js = d.createElement(s);
                        js.id = id;
                        js.async = true;
                        js.src = "//test.com/scripts/exposure.widgets.min.js";
                        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                    }
                })(document, "script", "ebt.widgets");
            </script>
        </pre>
```

Comment: what do you mean by event id change?

is there a reason you don't use jquery to populate the textbox once you have the text ready to insert? this would decouple it from knockout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping your code template inside a pre is likely doing weird things and making it more difficult for you.  Instead, I'd recommend using a string for your code template, like this:

```
var codeTemplate = 
'<div id="ebt-{0}" data-href="https://test.com/widgets/v1/{1}?eventid=@Model.EventId" data-width="100%" data-height="500px"></div>\n' +
'<script type="text/javascript">\n' +
'    (function (d, s, id) {\n' +
'        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];\n' +
'        if (!d.getElementById(id)) {\n' +
'          js = d.createElement(s);\n' +
'          js.id = id;\n' +
'          js.async = true;\n' +
'          js.src = "//test.com/scripts/exposure.widgets.min.js";\n' +
'          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);\n' +
'        }\n' +
'    })(document, "script", "ebt.widgets");\n' +
'<\/script>';
```

Then create a computed that will fill out the parameters in that template based on your observables:

```
app.viewModel.code = ko.computed(function() {
    var selected = app.viewModel.members.widgets.selectedWidget();
    if (selected) {
        var result = codeTemplate.replace('{0}',selected.id).replace('{1}',selected.id);
        return result;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
});
```

You can then drop the `initializeValueWithHtml` binding.

Here is a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/tlarson/Ycz5Q/

For the fiddle, I wasn't really sure what the types were supposed to be, because I don't have visibility into your server-side models, so I set them as 1 and 2.

To use the fiddle, type 1 into the first box, then tab off it.  Change the value in the first box to 2 then tab off it.  You should see the appropriate code load into the second box depending on the value in the first box.